# What's the exact use or purpose of MAT type in OpenCv

Tags: android, opencv, mat

I'm a rookie in openCv concept so please do excuse me if my question is foolish. I read about the several `matTpyes` available in `openCV` . But I'm unable to understand what's their use or purpose ?

Several matTypes are as :`CV_8U, CV_8S, CV_16U, CV_16S, CV_32S, CV_32F, CV_64F`

Means while declaring the mat objects for camera by changing the types 8U to 64F I'm unable to figure any changes (Are they helpful for resolution?)

Code:

```
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {

    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mRgbaF = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mRgbaT = new Mat(width, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CV_` is just a prefix

`8,16,32,64` number of bits per base matrix element

`F,U,S` type of the base element.F for float, S (signed) or U (unsigned)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer sir . so, is it used for the quality of image ?

Comment: Yeah you can say it is used for quality. Technically if your image contains multiple channels then you will need more bits in order to keep the channels so you will need different types.